# Rails: Including the '@' as part of a username link when using Twitter Text gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm currently using the (frankly amazing) Twitter Text gem to automatically set up links within a tweet's status for a Twitter widget I'm building.

However, when using the auto_link functionality on usernames (i.e. @adamt), it drops the '@' from the link text, outputting something like:

```
@<a href="twitter.com/adamt">adamt</a>
```

Does anyone know of a simple way to include in the '@' inside that link using the Twitter Text gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `:username_include_symbol => true` option ([from code](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb/blob/master/lib/twitter-text/autolink.rb)).

Comment: It ends up in `link_to_text_with_symbol`, I think, fwiw.

Comment: Thank you! I've been scouring the Twitter:AutoLink API and Google for the better part of an hour. Never occurred to me to look in the actual code. Hurr durr...

Comment: The code is always the most reliable source of documentation!

Comment: True story: Was just wondering how to add target="_blank" to all auto links. Then I checked the code...